# Replacing small HDD with Win 7 OS with larger HDD using Backup & Restore

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, backup, restore

I'm in the middle of replacing a small hard drive with Windows 7 installed on it with a larger hard drive. I've created a system image to an external hard drive. I've created a System Repair disk and I've shut down and removed the old drive. I put the hard drive jumper in the same location on the new hard drive and installed it. This is when the problem starts...

When I restart the computer and try to boot from the System repair disk I can select my CD/DVD drive but then I get a "no bootable device" error and am in an endless cycle of selecting the boot drive but it not finding a bootable device.

I've tried moving the jumper on the hard drive to other pins but that doesn't help. Originally they were on pins 5 & 6. I've tried 1 & 2 and other pins but didn't get anything. On top of this, when I try to put the old drive back on the computer I'm getting the same errors with a bootable device and no I don't have a functioning computer. Even the exact same setup with the original hard drive is now not working.

Any thoughts would help. I'm very confused that now the original setup doesn't even work.

Comment: Try removing both the hard drives and boot from the system repair disk. If it still shows the same issue, the problem lies in the system repair disk or the CD/DVD drive.